# R subscript out of bounds with for loops

Tags: r, if-statement, for-loop

I am trying to count entries that fall within a 1000 window, the problem is that I'm using for loops which makes the number of operations that need to be performed quite large (I'm fairly new to R) and I get an out of bounds error. I know there must be a better way to do this.

File (warning the file is a little over 100mb): [bamDF.txt](http://sdrv.ms/19zjgLc)

Use:

```
dget(file="bamDF.txt")
```

Script:

```
attach(bamDF)
out <- matrix(0,1,ceiling((max(pos, na.rm=TRUE)-min(pos, na.rm=TRUE))/interval))
interval <- 1000
for(q in 1:nrow(bamDF)){
  for(z in 1:ceiling((max(pos, na.rm=TRUE)-min(pos, na.rm=TRUE))/interval)){
    if(min(pos, na.rm=TRUE)+interval*(z-1)<pos[q]&&pos[q]<(min(pos, na.rm=TRUE)+interval*(z))){
      out[z,] <- out[z,]+1;


    }

  }


}
detach(bamDF)
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean with "fall within a 1000 window"?

Comment: Imagine you have a number line from 1-5000, so for a 1000 window/bin you would have 5 bins in that interval, then you would look at all the numbers that fall into each bin and count them. Hope that clarifies it a bit.

Comment: Does `table(cut(yourdatatocount, seq(0, 5000, 1000)))` do something close to what you're looking for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `cut` function

```
# set the seed to get a reproducible example
set.seed(12345)

min.val <- 0
max.val <- 5000
num.val <- 10000
# Generate some random values
values <- sample(min.val:max.val, num.val, replace=T)

interval <- 1000
num.split <- ceiling((max.val - min.val)/interval)+1

# Use cut to split the data. 
# You can set labels=FALSE if you want the group number 
# rather than the interval
groups <- cut(values, seq(min.val, max.val, length.out=num.split))

# Count the elements in each group
res <- table(groups)
```

`res` will contain:

```
groups
    (0,1e+03] (1e+03,2e+03] (2e+03,3e+03] (3e+03,4e+03] (4e+03,5e+03] 
         1987          1974          2054          2000          1984
```

---

Similarly, you can just use the `hist` function:

```
 h <- hist(values, 10) # 10 bins
```

or

```
 h <- hist(values, seq(min.val, max.val, length.out=num.split))
```

`h$counts` contains the counts. Use `plot=NULL` if you don't want to plot the results.

Comment: Interestingly this is what I got (quick question that has me a little worriedm will there be overlap between the cuts i.e. is the last value < or =<): `groups
      (1144,2144]    (2144,3143.99] (3143.99,4143.99] 
                1                 6               4     `

Comment: @crysis405: the right value is taken, the left is not (the `(` and  `]` are the standard mathematical notation for that). You can change the behaviour using the `right` parameter. The results seem weird, have you only got 11 values?

Comment: no I  got 249239 values which is right, but why doesn't it start from 0 like yours and why are there decimal places?

Comment: Well, whay is the range of your data? (try `range(data)`). The decimal come from the fact that evidently the interval does not fit correctly in the range. If you want to start from 0 impose some interval as I did. PS: I added another option, using `hist`

Comment: the range is from 1144 to 249239505, that explains it.

Answer (score 0):

```
grps <- seq(min(pos), max(pos), by= 1000)
counts <- table( findInterval( pos, c(grps, Inf) ) )
names(counts) <- grps
```